# Some fonts won't load while others do, using JavaFX 8 and CSS

Tags: css, fonts, javafx-8

I'm trying to skin my Java app with [Apple's San Francisco font](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/%20%22SF). I've tried every approach I've found, but remain unable to load the SF font while other custom fonts appear to work.

Following is my CSS code, which works if I use the TRON font from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css) but not with the SF fonts. The element with the ID `title` is a `Label` object where the text is set in the constructor and in addition to setting the ID, no other operations are performed. [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865343/loading-custom-font-using-javafx-8-and-css), I understand that this should work. Any idea why it does not?

*(Please note that whenever applicable, I've also tried "San Francisco", "SF, "SF UI" and "SF UI Text" in place of "SF UI Text Regular".)*

```
@font-face {
    src: url("SFText-Regular.otf");
}

#title .text {
    -fx-font-family: "SF UI Text Regular";
}
```

I'm using Java 1.8.0_121-b13 and JavaFX 8.0.121-b13.

**Other approaches I've tried**

The old CSS approach, to no avail:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SF";
    src: url("SFText-Regular.otf");
}

#title .text {
    -fx-font-family: "SF";
}
```

Loading and setting the font in-line ([from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/text/jfxpub-text.htm)):

```
title.setFont(Font.loadFont("file:SFText-Regular.otf", 10));
title.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'SF UI Text Regular';");
```

And finally separately loading the font ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12181948/7676920)):

```
Font.loadFont(ControlPane.class.getResource("SFText-Regular.otf").toExternalForm(), 10);
        title2.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'San Francisco';");
```

All of the above work for the TRON font but not for the SF fonts. Is it possible that this issue stems from their design or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Downloaded font from:

   https://www.fontify.me/cm/28ea2e32b70da0a2480848ba03cd6146/SF-UI-Text-Regular.ttf

   > That is just a random link from the internet, I don't know if it will stay good.
2. Placed the downloaded font in the same directory as the sample code below.
3. Right clicked on the file in OS X and chose "Get Info" to find out the font name.

   > In this case it is: `SF UI Text Regular`.
4. Ran the sample code.

With the SF UI Text Regular font:

[image: sample]

With the default font on my OS X 10.9.5 box (commenting out the `setStyle` line in the code):

[image: default]

The difference is subtle from the low quality screenshots provided, but more apparent when running the two side by side on my PC.

The font I used is a `.ttf` font rather than a `.otf` font.  I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Unfortunately, I can't sufficiently explain why the apple falls from the tree.

*san-fran.css*

```
@font-face {
    src: url("SF-UI-Text-Regular.ttf");
}
```

*SanFranFont.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SanFranFont extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label text = new Label("After dinner, the weather being warm, we went into the garden and drank thea, under the shade of some apple trees...he told me, he was just in the same situation, as when formerly, the notion of gravitation came into his mind. It was occasion'd by the fall of an apple, as he sat in contemplative mood. Why should that apple always descend perpendicularly to the ground, thought he to himself...");
        text.setWrapText(true);
        text.setPrefWidth(400);

        final Scene layout = new Scene(new StackPane(text));
        layout.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("san-fran.css").toExternalForm()
        );

        text.setStyle("-fx-font-family: \"SF UI Text Regular\";");

        stage.setScene(layout);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm having the same problem with Open Sans TTF-fonts, so likely the .otf format isn't an issue (or, at least, the only one) here.