# Null Pointer Exception when loading CSS file in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

This might be a very easy fix, I'm entirely new to JavaFX and CSS and I'm trying to add some CSS to my Scene.
The build runs, but the CSS obviously isn't working and I get a Null Pointer Exception in javafx.css.CssParser.

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family:'Quentin';
    src: url('/ui/font/Quentin.otf');
}


.textfield{

-fx-font-family: 'Quentin';

}

.button{ 
    -fx-font-family: 'Quentin';
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}

.textfield{
    -fx-background-color: null;
}
```

When I remove the @font-face block, the rest of the code runs fine and my buttons and text fields work and appear as expected. I'm not sure if the tutorials I'm looking up are following an old Java tutorial which is now updated.

For reference, the font 'Quentin' appears to be downloaded as Quentin.otf, but appears in the file explorer as Quentin-Regular.otf, as pictured.
[Quentin Font Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNKzN.png)
[Quentin Font in File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0lSH.png)

I have tried changing the file names to both instances, but no dice. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the font-family in font face or use -fx-font-family like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865343/loading-custom-font-using-javafx-8-and-css

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, George R. I tried this, and fiddled around with it but it still doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if your `src` folder structured something similar to this:

```
├── main
     ├── java
     |     └── ...
     |
     └── resources
             |
             ├── fonts
             |     └── Quentin.otf
             |
             └── stylesheet.css
```

Then in your stylesheet the font `src` will be:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quentin';
    src: url('fonts/Quentin.otf');
}
```

Secondly, the `TextField` style class is `.text-field` not `.textfield`.

Thirdly, `-fx-font-family: 'Quentin';` and `-fx-background-color: null;` can be in the same CSS block because they have the same class (`.text-field`).

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quentin';
    src: url('fonts/Quentin.otf');
}

.text-field {
    -fx-font-family: 'Quentin';
    -fx-background-color: null;
}

.button {
    -fx-font-family: 'Quentin';
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

Finally, you may want to add the stylesheet to a pane `pane.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");`

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help on the CSS, I fixed some things you pointed out.

Unfortunately, the font issue is still ongoing. It's a headscratcher for sure! The entire CSS now runs without me extracting the font-family block, so I'm not sure if now the issue is just an issue with overwriting the font applied in scenebuilder? (Given that I can override the font colour of Buttons, I'm not sure this is it).

Comment: I decided to delete and re-paste the fonts into the font folder in resource and restart my IDE, and it worked! 

I guess Eclipse's F5 to refresh wasn't working as well as it should. Thank you!